# Applying validation properly in custom form components in angular

Tags: angular, forms, validation, custom-element

I created a custom **select** like this:

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, forwardRef, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { ExtendedSelectOption } from '@app/core/models/common/common.model';
import { Is } from '@app/shared/utils/it';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-select',
  templateUrl: './custom-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-select.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomSelectComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CustomSelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() inputId: string;
  @Input()
  set ngModel(model: unknown) {
    // only update  ngModel and selected option on changed value
    if (this.selectedOption?.value !== model && !(
      Is.nullOrUndefined(this.selectedOption) && Is.nullOrUndefined(model))) {
      this.selectedOption = this.options.find(option => option.value === model)
      || null;
      this._ngModel = model;
    }
  }
  get ngModel(): unknown {
    return this._ngModel;
  }
  @Input() options: ExtendedSelectOption[] = [];
  @Input() inputClass: string;
  @Input() disabled: boolean = false;
  @Input() required: boolean = false;
  @Input() showLabel: boolean = false;
  @Input() labelText: string = null;
  @Input() inputName: string = null;
  @Output() triggerFocus = new EventEmitter<FocusEvent>();
  @Output() triggerClick = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
  @Output() triggerBlur = new EventEmitter<FocusEvent>();
  @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter<unknown>();

  private _ngModel: unknown = null;
  selectedOption: ExtendedSelectOption = null;

  onOptionChange(option: ExtendedSelectOption) {
    this._ngModel = option.value;
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this._ngModel);
  }

  // this fulfills NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR interface
  onChange: (value: unknown) => void = (value: unknown) => {};

  onTouched: () => void = () => {};

  writeValue(value: boolean): void {
    this.ngModel = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (value: unknown) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
}
```

with the corresponding template:

```html
<mat-icon
    class="inactive_select_icon"
    [title]="'Inactive ' + inputName"
    *ngIf="selectedOption?.disabled"
    >info_outline</mat-icon
  >
<select
  [attr.id]="inputId || null"
  [class]="inputClass"
  [class.inactive-select]="selectedOption?.disabled"
  [disabled]="disabled"
  [required]="required"
  [name]="inputName"
  (click)="triggerClick.emit()"
  (focus)="triggerFocus.emit()"
  (blur)="triggerBlur.emit()"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
  (ngModelChange)="onOptionChange($event);">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options"
    [ngValue]="option"
    [disabled]="option.disabled">
    {{option.label}}
  </option>
</select>
<label *ngIf="showLabel" class="u-ml--tiny" [for]="inputId || null">{{
  labelText
}}</label>
```

I can use it in a *form* just fine, I can set it to be *required* and when nothing is selected, the **internal select** element is then marked as **invalid**, but my **custom-select** component is marked as **valid**.

I can set the **control** of my **custom-select** to be **invalid** e.g. `control.get('someName').setErrors({someError: true}))`, which marks the **custom-select** as **invalid** but the **internal select** stays **valid**.

My question is how the validation should be done properly and what needs to be implemented to achieve this